# Rails: Render new data from controller to view?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, jquery, coffeescript

I have a rails app. When I click on a button I want it to load some new data into @posts in my controller, and show that in a render on the page.

In my view I have three buttons:

```
    <div class="span6 offset3" id="user_post_area_button">
        <div id="type_group" class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons-radio">
            <button class="radio_button" id="radio_button_zero" data-value="0">0</button>
            <button class="radio_button" id="radio_button_one" data-value="1">1</button>
            <button class="radio_button" id="radio_button_two" data-value="2">2</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When I click one of them I want some portion of my page to change. This is the portion I want to change (I want it to render with the new @posts):

```
<div class="render_post">
   <%= render 'pages/singlePost' %>
</div>
```

I use this .js.coffee code:

```
$ ->
  $("button.radio_button").click (e) ->
    e.preventDefault();
    list_status = $(this).data("value")
    if list_status == 0
      $("#radio_button_zero").addClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_one").removeClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_two").removeClass('active')
      $.post '/lelist/' + list_status
    else if list_status == 1
      $("#radio_button_zero").removeClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_one").addClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_two").removeClass('active')
      $.post '/lelist/' + list_status
    else if list_status == 2
      $("#radio_button_zero").removeClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_one").removeClass('active')
      $("#radio_button_two").addClass('active')
      $.post '/lelist/' + list_status
```

And here is my controller:

```
class PagesController < ApplicationController
    def lelist
        if current_user && params[:list_status] == 0
          @posts = Post.where("created_at <= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 0).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
        elsif current_user && params[:list_status] == 1
          @posts = Post.where("created_at <= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 1).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
        elsif current_user && params[:list_status] == 2
          @posts = Post.where("created_at <= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 2).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
        elsif !current_user || current_user
          @posts = Post.where("created_at <= ? AND status = ?", Time.now, 0).order("created_at DESC").page(params[:page]).per_page(10)
        end
    end
end
```

I just can't figure out how to make this work. Some suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

What you need to use are AJAX calls

Since it is an extensive subject, I can not start explaining about it here

You can start by reading about it here

http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/working_with_javascript_in_rails.html#an-introduction-to-ajax

Here is more detailed manual

http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/using-unobtrusive-javascript-and-ajax-with-rails-3/

Enjoy